# plotting line data in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am doing a research project on the north south divide, and have asked people to draw on a simple outline of England where they feel the north south divide should be in England. However, I am unsure how to now accurately plot this into Arcmap.

Comment: "The North–South divide is not an exact line" it is a feeling - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North%E2%80%93South_divide_%28England%29

Answer (score 1):

"Accurately" is probably going to be a relative term. If you've had them draw on some small scale graphic (say, an 8.5x11), then you could scan them all in and georeference the images to an actual shapefile of the country outline, then create a new line feature class and draw each person's line in with whatever identifying attributes you choose. However given the accuracy of the original lines, georeferencing may simply be overkill. It may be just as accurate (and a *lot* less time consuming) to load up the outline and draw your own lines by eyeballing the study graphics. It's unlikely people would be drawing lines on such an exhibit that one made sure a town was *just* north of the line while the other made sure it was *just* south of it (or if they tried that they'd actually get it right on a simple outline).